# According to whom breakfast is healthy?

Tags: diet, metabolism, breakfast

I've certainly been taught breakfast is the most important meal of the day because while you sleep it's the longest period of time the body goes without food. Someone told me today that there is no science behind this claim. I did a Google search and there are roughly the same number of articles supporting breakfast is [good](https://www.google.com/search?q=is%20eating%20in%20the%20morning%20healthy&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a#client=firefox-a&hs=Hrc&hl=en&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&sclient=psy-ab&q=why%20breakfast%20is%20good%20for%20you&oq=why%20breakfast%20is%20good%20for%20you&gs_l=serp.3..0j0i5i30l2j0i8i30.412890.413308.5.413494.5.5.0.0.0.2.129.551.2j3.5.0...0.0...1c.1.11.psy-ab.b9OLwLc9bkI&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.45645796,d.cGE&fp=2ec0b9d6037ebe57&biw=1920&bih=956) vs breakfast is [bad](https://www.google.com/search?q=is%20eating%20in%20the%20morning%20healthy&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a#client=firefox-a&hs=EBI&hl=en&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&sclient=psy-ab&q=why%20breakfast%20is%20bad%20for%20you&oq=why%20breakfast%20is%20bad&gs_l=serp.3.1.0l2j0i22i30l2.42065.42342.4.43574.3.3.0.0.0.0.82.232.3.3.0...0.0...1c.1.11.psy-ab.70sTgLAMD6o&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.45645796,d.cGE&fp=2ec0b9d6037ebe57&biw=1920&bih=956).

Comment: I think this is off topic here ([faq]), but it might be on topic on [skeptics.se] after some rephrasing.

Comment: It is already on Skeptics: http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/755/is-breakfast-the-most-important-meal-of-the-day